# How to make `where not` case?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I need where but with **not** case. For example, I would like to find plays, which have no name "Shakespeare":

```
_.where(listOfPlays, {author: !"Shakespeare", year: 1611});
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                            NOT Shakespeare
```

How can I do it with `underscore`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
_.filter(listOfPlays, function(play) {
    return play.author !== 'Shakespeare' && play.year === 1611;
});
```

http://underscorejs.org/#filter

`where` is nothing more than a convenient wrapper around `filter`:

```
// Convenience version of a common use case of `filter`: selecting only objects
// containing specific `key:value` pairs.
_.where = function(obj, attrs) {
    return _.filter(obj, _.matches(attrs));
};
```

https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/a6c404170d37aae4f499efb185d610e098d92e47/underscore.js#L249

Comment: I think, it would be usefull to have `_.not()` wrapper as well. For example, `_.not(listOfPlays, {author: "Shakespeare"})`.

Answer (score 7):

You can cook your own "not where" version of `_.where` like this

```
_.mixin({
    "notWhere": function(obj, attrs) {
        return _.filter(obj, _.negate(_.matches(attrs)));
    }
});
```

And then you can write your code like this

```
_.chain(listOfPlays)
    .where({
        year: 1611
    })
    .notWhere({
        author: 'Shakespeare'
    })
    .value();
```

**Note:** [`_.negate`](http://underscorejs.org/#negate) is available only from v1.7.0. So, if you are using previous version of `_`, you might want to do something like this

```
_.mixin({
    "notWhere": function(obj, attrs) {
        var matcherFunction = _.matches(attrs);
        return _.filter(obj, function(currentObject) {
            return !matcherFunction(currentObject);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, it would be cool! Thank you! One remark, it would be better to name the function as `not()`.

Comment: @Warlock we already have a function called [`_.negate`](http://underscorejs.org/#negate), so `not` and `negate` might be confusing...

Comment: @Warlock But remember, `_.negate` is available only from v1.7.0

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of right answers, but technically the OP just asked about negating. You can also use reject, it's essentially the opposite of filter. To achieve the compound condition of 1611 and not Shakespeare:

```
_.reject(_.filter(listOfPlays, function(play){
    return play.year === 1611
}), function(play) {
  return play.author === 'Shakespeare';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
_.filter(listOfPlays,function(i){
    return i['author']!='Shakespeare' && i['year']==1611;
});
```